# how to debug custom workflow activities in visual studio 2010

Tags: sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-workflow, workflow-activity

I have been searching the web for an answer to my problem, but so far I have not been lucky.
I have create a custom workflow activity and I would like to debug it in visual studio 2010, but I don't know how to do it.

Any help will be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to attach visual studio to the process that is running on the server.

[Here is the MSDN article on it](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms455354.aspx)

Some more resources regarding remote debugging:

[Debugging with Visual Studio extensions for Windows SharePoint Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650703.aspx)

[Debug SharePoint Applications](http://lemonharpy.wordpress.com/2011/03/17/remote-debugging-sharepoint-2010-solutions/)